# Permission denied (publickey) for public github vue-i18n-loader

Tags: github

I have a permission denied when i try to connect to public github vue-i18n-loader and i don't know why

`git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader.git git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`